# Using Microsoft.Graph to get current application permissions

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

My C# program uses the Microsoft.Graph Nuget. And it needs be able to ensure that it has the correct Microsoft Graph application permissions.

I know how to add permissions in AD, but I want my program to be able test it has the permissions it needs.

Example of what I want to achieve :

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

if(!graphClient.GetPermissions().Contains("AdministrativeUnit.Read.All"))
{
    throw new Exception("Missing Permission AdministrativeUnit.Read.All")
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a long way.

Here I provide a general idea of Microsoft Graph beta version(through HTTP method):

1. Get the Object ID of the servicePrincipal based on the App ID: `GET
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq
   '{App ID}'`.
2. Get the appRole information (the application permission information)
   based on the Object ID from step 1: `GET
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{Object ID}/appRoleAssignedTo`.
   [image]
3. Get a match list of appRoleID and Microsoft Graph application permission name: `GET
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq
   '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'`. Please note that
   "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" is a fixed value， which
   represents the App ID of the Microsoft internal Graph App.
   [image]
4. Compare the results of the 2nd and 3rd steps and you will know which
   application permissions are in your Azure AD app.

By the way, [Get appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) is only available in beta version currently, but beta version api is not recommended to use.

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, I was challenged with the same issue and I want to share my solution which I find a lot more practical and easier to understand.

Introduce these two helper methods into your code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Decodes a JWT token to a decoded string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="jwtToken">The JWT token to decode.</param>
/// <returns>The decoded string representation of the JWT token.</returns>
public static string DecodeJwtToken(string jwtToken)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    if (tokenHandler.CanReadToken(jwtToken))
    {
        var decodedToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);
        return decodedToken.ToString();
    }

    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT token.");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Extracts the "roles" array from a JWT security token.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="jwtToken">The JWT security token from which to extract the roles array.</param>
/// <returns>A list of strings representing the roles extracted from the JWT security token.</returns>
public static List<string> ExtractRolesFromJwtSecurityToken(string jwtToken)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var securityToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(jwtToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
 
    if (securityToken != null)
    {
        var rolesClaims = securityToken.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "roles");
        if (rolesClaims != null)
        {
            var roleStrings = rolesClaims.Select(claim => claim.Value.Replace("roles:", "").Trim()).ToList();
            return roleStrings;
        }
    }
 
    // If roles claim is not found or cannot be extracted, return an empty list or handle the error accordingly.
    return new List<string>();
}
```

These two can be used like this:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();
var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

var jwtToken = authResult.AccessToken;

// use this if you want to inspect the entire token
var decodedToken = DecodeJwtToken(jwtToken);

// and if you're lazy, this. The result will be like {"Mail.Read", "Mail.Write", ... }
var permissions = ExtractRolesFromJwtSecurityToken(jwtToken);
```