# List all users and the installed apps with scopes - Office 365

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

how to get the list of users, applications/add-ins installed by user/admin and the associated scopes?
I could able to get the users using graph API, and the installed apps(add-ins). But for all the installed add-ins I am getting scope as user_impersonation instead of getting specific scopes like User.Read.All, User.Export.All etc.

Comment: Hi Krishna, could you tell me how do you list the installed apps(add-ins)? With which endpoint? It's appreciated if you could provide the full request.

Comment: Hi Allen, I am using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userId>/appRoleAssignments to get the installed add-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which kind of permissions you want to list. Application permission or Delegated permission?

In my experience, scope means Delegated permission. (roles means Application permission)

So now that you have list the apps via `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments`, you should be able to see `resourceId` in the response.

[image]

Then you could call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{resourceId get from the step above}/oauth2PermissionGrants` to get the scope.

[image]

This method only gets the Delegated permissions. If you want to list Application permissions, please refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584248/using-microsoft-graph-to-get-current-application-permissions/58638169#58638169).

If you have any other questions please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you Allen Wu. oauth2PermissionGrants is the one that I am looking for.